# Passing Pointer to Structure using Java Native Access Library(JNA)

Tags: java

Is it possible to pass pointer to structure using JNA? Suppose I have a method now i want to call this method using java.

void calculate_Hx(struct a *);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: yes. JNA lets you manipulate `struct` and `union` objects from Java, including passing them as arguments to functions. [Here's](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/StructuresAndUnions.md) a relevant bit of the documentation.